# Can't remove commas in filenames on Linux

Tags: linux, filenames, rename

I have folder named 'data' in the terminal folder. Some of the file names in data have a ',' in them. I am able to list them by

```
$ cd data
$ ls -i |grep -E '\,'
```

But I don't know how to remove ',' from those filenames. From my research I tried something like `grep -E '\,' | sed ','` but it did not work. 
If I can't remove the commas from the file filenames, I am willing to delete those files but I can't delete them either (it says no such file or directory)
on terminal folder or with the command line using rm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the bash shell, you could loop over all of the filenames that have a comma in them and rename them to remove all the commas:

```
for f in *,*; do mv -- "$f" "${f//,/}"; done
```

With a sample run:

```
$ touch foo,bar a,b,c,d
$ ls
a,b,c,d  foo,bar
```

The results are:

```
$ for f in *,*; do mv -- "$f" "${f//,/}"; done
$ ls
abcd  foobar
```

This will clobber any destination filenames that already exist.